# Gyroscope and Dragging working together in a 3d room

Tags: unity-game-engine, math, 3d, drag, gyroscope

I'm working on an app in unity, which is basically a 3D room and the user can use the phone's gyroscope to navigate around the room.
The issue I'm having is, I also want the user to be able to drag the room, while the gyro still works after the drag is finished, but my code for dragging doesn't work that well, and it also breaks the gyrosocope navigation.

I made a video to explain the issue better: https://youtu.be/7liSyZAdxL4

This is my code for the gyrsocope (it's attached to the camera):

```
using UnityEngine;
public class GyroHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
bool m_gyroEnabled;
UnityEngine.Gyroscope m_gyro;
GameObject m_gyroParent;
Quaternion m_rotation;
float m_rotateAmount = 0;

public static GyroHandler Instance;

void Awake()
{
    Instance = this;
}

void Start()
{
    Screen.sleepTimeout = SleepTimeout.NeverSleep;
    ResetGyro();
}


void ResetGyro()
{
    m_gyroParent = new GameObject("Gyro Parent");
    m_gyroParent.transform.position = transform.position;
    transform.SetParent(m_gyroParent.transform);
    m_gyroEnabled = EnableGyro();
}


bool EnableGyro()
{
    if (SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope)
    {
        m_gyro = Input.gyro;
        m_gyro.enabled = true;
        m_gyroParent.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(90f, -90f, 0f);
        m_rotation = new Quaternion(0, 0, 1, 0);
        return true;
    }
    else
        Debug.Log("Device doesn't support gyro.");
    return false;
}

void Update()
{
    if (m_gyroEnabled && SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope)
    {
        transform.localRotation = m_gyro.attitude * m_rotation;
        transform.Rotate(0, -m_rotateAmount, 0);
    }
}


public void ToggleGyro(bool enable, float rotateAmount)
{
    m_rotateAmount += rotateAmount;
    m_gyroEnabled = enable;

}
}
```

and this is my code for dragging the room:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class RoomDragHandler : MonoBehaviour, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler
{
    float m_rotateAmount = 0;

    public void OnDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        GyroHandler.Instance.ToggleGyro(false, 0);
        float speedx = eventData.delta.x * 0.05f;
        m_rotateAmount += speedx;
        Camera.main.transform.Rotate(0, -speedx, 0);
    }

    public void OnEndDrag(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        GyroHandler.Instance.ToggleGyro(true, m_rotateAmount);
        m_rotateAmount = 0;
    }
}
```

My logic for dragging is this: when the dragging starts, disable the gyro, and after the drag is finished, enable the gyro back. And while the user is dragging, save the drag amount in a variable (m_rotateAmount) and when the drag is finished, pass that value to gyro handler, so that when the gyro takes over again, it turn rotate the camera to that amount. Without that part, as soon as the drag is over, the room will snap back, so we need to tell the gyro to do that additional rotation. This is the part of the code that does that :

```
void Update()
{
    if (m_gyroEnabled && SystemInfo.supportsGyroscope)
    {
        transform.localRotation = m_gyro.attitude * m_rotation;
        transform.Rotate(0, -m_rotateAmount, 0);
    }
}
```

first part just does the normal rotation with gyro and the 2nd line adds the extra rotation that was saved during the dragging.

I am not sure what I'm missing but I've been playing with this code, trying to figure out the math better to see why the drag breaks the gyro, but so far no luck.

If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

By default transform.Rotate(x, y, z) rotates around the object's local coordinate system, not the world coordinate system. This means that when you apply the dragging rotation after applying the gyro rotation the y-axis is no longer pointing straight up, and the applied rotation is not necessarily in the expected direction.

---

To fix this use:

```
transform.Rotate(0, -m_rotateAmount, 0, Space.World)
```